# VBA raising errors from within Class modules (with Class_Initialize) fails

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I've been trying to implement error handling in class modules so I can log if users face any bugs ,and in which module/class did it happen.

my approach is to handle error reporting in the calling sub/function and and use err.raise in called sub/function to bubble-up the error to the calling sub.

This worked okay for modules (calling modules from within a module), But when I tested for raising errors from within class modules it gave me Error #  440 Automation error instead of the actual error (like type mismatch for ex).

I boiled down the (bug?) to the fact that the Err object is not initialized for some reason after class_Initialize is run, I'm using Excel 2016; Application.Version = 16.

For Example the following module calls a class property:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestCRef()

On Error GoTo ErrHandlr

    Dim y As New CellRef
    'Call y.SetRef  'normal behavior when Class_Initialize() is commented and this is used instead
    Debug.Print y.CstOrdrNo
    
Exit Sub
ErrHandlr:

    If Err.Source = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.Name Then
        Err.Source = "Module1.TestCRef"
    End If
    
    Dim ErrStr As String
    ErrStr = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & ", was generated by :" _
                    & Err.Source & ", Description : " & Err.Description
                    
    Debug.Print (ErrStr)
    
End Sub
```

the class module (CellRef):

```
Option Explicit

Public CstOrdrNo As Range
Private x As Integer
    
    
Sub Class_Initialize()

On Error GoTo ErrHandlr

    x = "Bug" 'intentional
    Set CstOrdrNo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

Exit Sub
ErrHandlr:
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5050, "CellRef.Class_Initialize", "Error While Initializing Class"
End Sub

'Used instead of Class_Initialize
Sub SetRef()
On Error GoTo ErrHandlr

    x = "Bug" 'intentional
    Set CstOrdrNo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    
Exit Sub
ErrHandlr:
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5050, "CellRef.SetRef", "Error While Intializing x"
End Sub
```

**First Case:** Class_Initialize is used to set the range when called the first time, error occurs.
*Expected behavior:-* Error # -2147216454, was generated by :CellRef.SetRef, Description : Error While Initializing Class.
*What happens:-* Error #  440, was generated by :Module1.TestCRef, Description : Automation error.
**Second Case:** Class_Initialize is commented and SetRef is used instead
*behavior:* Expected behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already know `Class_Initialize` raises error

> 440: Automation error

when any error is raised directly inside it.

But nevertheless `Class_Initialize` can bubble any error up like any other procedure.

So I use this paradigma, where I place the code of `Class_Initialize` into a new procedure `ClassInitialize` and call it from `Class_Initialize`:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ClassInitialize
End Sub

Private Sub ClassInitialize()
    On Error GoTo Catch

   Any code here ...

Done:
    Exit Sub

Catch:
    Err.Raise ...
End Sub
```

So I can raise any error I need in `ClassInitialize` and `Class_Initialize` will let it bubble up to its caller.

Adapted to your sample is looks like this:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ClassInitialize
End Sub

Private Sub ClassInitialize()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandlr

    x = "Bug" 'intentional
    Set CstOrdrNo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")

    Exit Sub

ErrHandlr:
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5050, "CellRef.Class_Initialize", "Error While Initializing Class"
End Sub
```

Also be aware of handling runtime errors in `Class_Terminate`:

A runtime error in the procedure `Class_Terminate` of a class (no matter if raised by `Err.Raise` itself or not) without a local error handler leads to an uncatchable runtime error with a standard error handler message box (the behavior is the same as with event handler procedures).

So in `Class_Terminate` (like in event handler procedures too) **always** a 'local' error handler must be enabled!

And because this error handler can not bubble up errors, you have to handle runtime errors in `Class_Terminate` locally, at all.

Comment: Thank you, I've been struggling with this for a day now, Also thanks for the Class_Terminate Tip.

Comment: I didn't try the ClassInitialize trick in other classes because I did so in an Acess DB class I wrote (Using MS Activex Data Objects 6.0 library) and Err.raise didn't work (Method or data member not found), but I guess it's because I need to use ADODB.Connection.Errors to catch Errors in the DB class.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thanks a lot. I'm curious though. You write `Class_Initialize raises error 440: Automation error when any error is raised directly inside it.` which, apparently, is true. But can you point to an official source for corroboration? I couldn't find anything myself.

Comment: No, sorry, I also couldn't find an official statement from Microsoft. Just a few references regarding in the wilds of users who stumbled over this too.